# How can I give permissions for folders in Linux?

Tags: permissions, users, chmod

I have to create

```
company/lawyers
Company/accountants
Company/users/Tim
Company/users/Mike
Company/users/Rob
Company/users/Ann
```

I also have to give permission to make changes for company only to root, permission to create and delete files in lawyers only to lawyers group members and likewise for accountants.

In the users folder nobody should be able to make changes, and for name folders only people who have same names can make changes.

I've added the users and created lawyers and accountant groups. But I can't seem to understand how to use the `chmod` command in this cases.

If I want to give read write execute permission to root for company folder I have to write `chmod u+rwx company`

For the second case `chmod u+rx, g+rwx, o+rx`

But how can I specify which groups can do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the folder to a particular group, for example to assign `Company/lawyers` to the `lawyers` group, use the command:

```
chgrp lawyers Company/lawyers
```

The first argument to `chgrp` command is the group, the second (and optionally third, fourth etc.) argument(s) is the folder or file you want to assign to that group. This command should be run as root, so if you're not running this from root, use `sudo`.

BTW. I suggest to use `chmod u+rx, g+rwxs, o+rx` in the second case (note the additional `s` in group field). This will automatically assign all files created within the folder to the same group as the folder.

Comment: Thank you very much !